# MsCorLib Array.cs Array.Sort line of code that not compile

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory-management

in th MsCorLib Array.cs source file there is the following Method, at line 1941:

```
void Sort<T>(T[] array)
```

in the body block at line 1948 there is the followin line

```
var span = new Span<T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(array), array.Length);
```

if i try to copy paste this line on a my project, with C# 11 and .NET 7, there is a compile error "Argument 1 may not be passed with 'ref' keyword"

How is possible this? Waht i have to do to compile this line?

[image]

Comment: That constructor of `Span` may be internal so you can not access it from your code.

Comment: no is not internal, the problem is with ref MemoryMarshal

Comment: It is not the same source it seems : [github](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/array.cs#L1948)

Comment: my bad, the line code that i have paste was from go to definition from visual studio. I will update with the right line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [internal `Span<T>` constructor](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs,131) which is not publicly available:

```cs
#pragma warning disable IDE0060 // https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/6228
// Constructor for internal use only. 
// It is not safe to expose publicly, 
// and is instead exposed via the unsafe MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan.
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
internal Span(ref T reference, int length)
{
    Debug.Assert(length >= 0);
 
    _reference = ref reference;
    _length = length;
}
#pragma warning restore IDE0060 // https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/6228
```

So "outside" compiler has only ctor with 2 parameters available - [`Span<T>(Void*, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-span-1-ctor(system-void*-system-int32)) which requires pointer, not a `ref` parameter, hence the compilation error.

As mentioned in the comment in the source - you can use [`MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createspan?view=net-7.0) as a substitute.

Comment: So according to comment OP can use `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(array), array.Length)`

Comment: @Eldar yes, thought that original comment was enough =) Added mention of `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan` to the answer.